# $_Post Doesnt Work [Undefined index]

Tags: php, post

Giris.php (login screen)

```
  <html>
          <form method="post" action="verify.php">
          <p>Birinci Isletim Sistemi:</p> <input type="text" name="txt_biris"><br><br>
          <p>Ikinci Isletim Sistemi:</p> <input type="text" name="txt_ikis"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Karşılaştır!">
          </form>
                </body>
</html>
```

Verify.php

```
    <?php
$ad = $_POST["txt_biris"];
echo"Ad...: $ad";
$sifre = $_POST["txt_ikis"];
echo "Sifre...: $sifre";
```

It returns..

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxoLg.png)

[image]

I tried many ways, controlled variables etc. But i didnt fix it. I'm using PHP 7 on Apache 2.4.17.

Comment: Still blank page after using isset()? And errors?

Comment: Open your **php.ini** page, what value is set for `post_max_size` & `upload_max_filesize` ?

Comment: post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 2M
@NanaPartykar

Comment: Yes, still blank page.

Comment: And what r u getting in `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: Try to make `php_value upload_max_filesize = 16M` & 
`php_value post_max_size = 16M` & `memory_limit = 128M` @AytaçGenç

Comment: I'm getting "Array ()" when i did that. @devpro. Thanks for answer. nanapartykar it's still blank page. Thanks for your answer, too.

Comment: Have you restart your xampp server after making changes @AytaçGenç ?

Comment: Form is not working.. Before increasing post max size on `error_reporting()`

Comment: And also restart the apache as NANA suggest

Comment: @NanaPartykar i'm using wampp server. I restarted all services 3 times. But still returns "Array()". I dont what should i do? Isnt there any other way? Get works still very fine. But i cant use post with password, as you guess.

Comment: Hello @nana-partykar are u ready for PAKISTAN vs INDIA today :)

Comment: And what about `print_r($_REQUEST)`

Comment: It returns "Array ()", too.

Comment: Ohh man how it possible.. If `$_GET` working fine it must be work fine with `$_REQUEST`

Comment: Is **Giris.php** is in this location **C:\Users\Deni\Desktop\My_Site\** Check It @AytaçGenç

Comment: Sorry my bad. When i used Get at form page $_REQUEST returns  Array ( [txt_biris] => debian [txt_ikis] => ubuntu )

Comment: If directory is also same than add `php_value post_max_size 60M
php_value upload_max_filesize 60M` in htaccess

Comment: But u can't use GET becuase of login page

Comment: I made a website with get. But i should make a admin panel with post. I'm begginner but this error make me feel foolish :)) There is no htaccess :?

Comment: Htaccess file located at main root

Comment: Still same error. "Array ()" Is there any chance if i should reinstall wampp server?

Comment: Check if `$_POST` is set to be populated in php.ini

Comment: Hmm now only one thing left change your input name `name="myfirstVal"` same as for second..

Comment: @Nordenheim there is only 1 "$_POST" word in php.ini file. It was in comment.

Comment: No @devpro it changed anything. But thanks for all of your answers.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
<?php
if(isset( $_POST["txt_biris"]))
{
    $ad = $_POST["txt_biris"];
    echo"Ad...: $ad";
    $sifre = $_POST["txt_ikis"];
    echo "Sifre...: $sifre";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But it returns blank page.

Comment: You need to click on submit button.

Comment: I clicked. But still same. I pasted your code verify.php. True?

Comment: I dont see any reason to delete or downvote my answer which is based on question. If you've not got your answer may be you should update you r question more precisely. Any php experienced could easily  judge question and answer relations here.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didnt make it. I've no enough rep to upvote it. So, i ve nothing to do